# What is the recommended way to launch a DialogFragment from a ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-databinding

I have a list objects in a `Recyclerview`. When long-pressing an item I want to show a dialog with data from the item clicked.

The `Recyclerview` is using data binding for each item and I am able to display data from the selected item using Log when long-pressing.

When trying to show a dialog, however, you need to get to the `Activity`, which is not recommended to use in the `ViewModel` object.

So how can I show the dialog?

Thanks, Ove

Comment: Conceptually a ViewModel strikes me as the wrong place to launch a Dialog from. To do it more cleanly I would pass the RecyclerView.ViewHolder into the layout, and have a method on the ViewHolder that triggers a custom listener on your RecyclerView.Adapter. Then whoever subscribes to that listener (Activity/Fragment) can launch the Dialog. May seem a little roundabout, but I don't think a ViewModel of a list item should have knowledge or control of its environment.

Comment: @Ulli Conseptually I agree. Could you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conceptually a ViewModel strikes me as the wrong place to launch a Dialog from. To do it more cleanly I would pass the RecyclerView.ViewHolder into the layout, and have a method on the ViewHolder that triggers a custom listener on your RecyclerView.Adapter. Then whoever subscribes to that listener (Activity/Fragment) can launch the Dialog. May seem a little roundabout, but I don't think a ViewModel of a list item should have knowledge or control of its environment.

Here is an example. This is a general pattern for handling RecyclerView item clicks with data binding and a ViewModel. This is not a complete example, just the code to highlight this specific pattern.

Layout:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <data>
    <variable
        name="viewHolder"
        type="com.example.ViewHolder"
        />
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.ViewModel"
        />
    </data>

    <com.example.View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewHolder.onClick(viewModel)}"
        />
</layout>
```

Adapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public interface SelectionListener {
        void onSelectionChanged(int newPosition, ViewModel viewModel);
    }

    private @NonNull WeakReference<SelectionListener> selectionListener =
            new WeakReference<>(null);

    public void setSelectionListener(@Nullable SelectionListener listener) {
        selectionListener = new WeakReference<>(listener);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder<ViewBinding> {
        ViewHolder(ViewBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());

            binding.setViewHolder(this);
            binding.setViewModel(new ViewModel());
        }

        public void onClick(ViewModel viewModel) {
            SelectionListener listener = selectionListener.get();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onSelectionChanged(getAdapterPosition(), viewModel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

See the [Variables](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#variables) section of the official documentation of the Data Binding Library. There you find a variable `context` you can use.

> A special variable named context is generated for use in binding expressions as needed. The value for context is the Context from the root View's `getContext()`. The context variable will be overridden by an explicit variable declaration with that name.

Basically you could just pass it to another variable like the `viewModel` to show the dialog from there.

```
android:onClick="@{v -> viewModel.showDialog(context)}"
```

Comment: Will it be okay to use such context in the ViewModel pattern ?

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 I think the real issue with the context inside a ViewModel is when you hold a reference.

Comment: This abuses the ViewModel to become a sort of Presenter. A ViewModel is responsible for the *data* in your View (which may be a Fragment or Activity with an associated XML databinding layout).

Answer (score 1):

I think using a binding adapter for a recyclerview and put the adapter n ViewModel, then make the viewmodel is the model of fragment and passing adapter for the setAdapter method in xml itself.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the context of item for example `itemView.getContext()` to show `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 0):

The hint from Bayoudh led me in the right direction, but I'm posting this to put the pieces together. Below is a cardview that is clickable. Since my `ViewModel` holds no reference to the activity we have to pass the view in question as a parameter.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardviewContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_margin_0.5x"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_margin_0.5x"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_margin_0.5x"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onClick(view)}" >
```

The `android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onClick(view)}"` statement takes the current view as a parameter so you can use it in the ViewModel to get context with `view.getContext()` as Bayoudh states.

Comment: You could also use a method reference `android:onClick="@{viewModel::onClick}"`

Comment: @tynn What do you mean? Is this not what I refer to in the answer? If you're not passing view as parameter how are you getting an activity reference?

Comment: It's equivalent to what you wrote, just shorter. Just wanted to point this out.