# Android Data Binding with RecyclerView custom onItemTouchListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener, android-databinding

I have gotten a pretty good hang of Android Data Binding but I am stuck on the last thing in my app that I have not been able to bind with data binding yet.  I have a `RecyclerView` on which I have implemented a custom touch listener to handle short clicks and long clicks.  I am just not sure WHAT exactly I am supposed to bind.  Is it even possible to use data binding for an onItemTouchListener?  I will paste the code I have, and hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction by telling me what I should be trying to bind, or if there is even a point.

The touch listener:

```
public class RecyclerViewTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
{
    private RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public RecyclerViewTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recycleView, final RecyclerViewClickListener cl)
    {
        this.clickListener = cl;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
            {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
            {
                View child = recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && cl != null)
                {
                    cl.onLongClick(child, recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e)
    {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e))
        {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept)
    {
    }
}
```

The click listener:

```
public interface RecyclerViewClickListener
{
    void onClick(View view, int position);
    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
```

The current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="activity"
            type="com.redacted.ListActivity"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.redacted.ListActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listRv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/addItemFab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{activity::fabClicked}"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccentLight"
            fab:fab_size="normal"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

My activity:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private OrderedRealmCollection<MyObject> allItems;
    private Realm realm;
    private ActivityListBinding b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        b = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_list);
        b.setActivity(this);

        setSupportActionBar(b.toolbar);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        CreateViewModel();

        b.listRv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        b.listRv.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(allItems, true));
        b.listRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        b.listRv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewTouchListener(this,
                b.listRv, new RecyclerViewClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position)
            {
                //unimportant code
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position)
            {
                //unimportant code
            }
        }));
    }

    private void CreateViewModel()
    {
        ListViewModel vm = new ListViewModel(realm);
        allItems = vm.getAllItems();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        b.listRv.setAdapter(null);
        realm.close();
    }

    public void fabClicked(View view)
    {
        //unimportant code
    }
}
```

My goal is to have `OnClick` and `OnLongClick` bound in the XML somehow.  If there is a better way to handle short and long press on `RecyclerView` items, you can tell me I am doing things the wrong way too.

Comment: It's an antipattern to do a click listener for items that's set on the entire RecyclerView. Do per-item listeners instead. I posted an example for per-item handling with databinding here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783116/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-launch-a-dialogfragment-from-a-viewmodel/42795719#42795719

Comment: @Uli Do you have a gist or sample project where you use this?  It looks like a good solution, I am just not sure how I could extend it to handle both kinds of click events.  I am not sure what the SelectionListener is doing in your example.

Comment: I don't have a complete example, but it is easy to extend. Wherever it says "onClick", add "onLongClick". The SelectionListener just propagates the click events up to the Activity; you would not need it if your event actions don't need activity-level capabilities. You can handle the click events in the adapter or ViewHolder. Whatever you do, don't follow the path that you took originally. You should be able to find examples similar to mine, it's pretty standard.

Comment: I was able to figure it out, thanks :) I got my click events in the view holder instead of on the whole recycler view. I thought some things weren't working since Android Studio says it does not recognize​ android:onLongClick but everything still builds and works fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: if the answer that I linked help you solve your problem, I'd appreciate if you'd upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to have OnClick and OnLongClick bound in the XML somehow

I would go for two different interface, if I were in you. But that's just a matter of taste. To bind it you need a binding adapter:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@BindingAdapter("onItemClickListener")
public static <T> void setOnItemClickListener(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener) {
   if (recyclerView instanceof RecyclerViewTouchListener) {
        ((RecyclerViewTouchListener) recyclerView).setItemClickListener(clickListener);
   }
}
```

and, of course, your `RecyclerViewTouchListener`, should declare a setter for `RecyclerViewClickListener`. And in your layout, you should have something like

```
  <your.package.to.RecyclerViewTouchListener
       app:onItemClickListener="@{yourViewModel.getRecyclerViewClickListener()}"
```