# How to initialise click listener on Recycler view adapter using Databinding?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, recyclerview-layout

I am going to make an universal adapter for all dynamic layouts , normally i handled all this things but i got stuck that how to initialise click listener using interface so that i define in whatever xml and get event in my class.

i am following this link:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

suppose this is my root xml of recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
<variable name="handlers" type="com.example.MyHandlers"/>
<variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@{user.firstName}"
android:onClick="@{handlers::onClickFriend}"
//>>> i want to initialise interface for position/view instead of @{handlers::onClickFriend}.
  />
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Please give me link and solution , i will be thankful to you.

Comment: This will point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42795719/436417

Comment: i am not possible to get :   binding.setViewModel(new ViewModel());                   i mention view model in xml  also but i am getting only binding.setVariable .   here is my xml:                                                                                         <data>


        <variable name="user" type="com.learn2crack.databinding.User"/>
        <variable name="viewHolder" type="com.learn2crack.databinding.BooksRecyclerAdapter.BindingHolder"/>

    </data>

Comment: finally i solve it  using this  holder.getBinding().setVariable(com.package.BR.viewHolder, holder);

Comment: You may be using the wrong "ViewBinding" class in the ViewHolder. Use the binding class that is generated from the xml file that you just quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass either user/position. If you want to pass position inside clickListener you must have to pass it as variable in xml same as user, and then

```
android:onClick="@{() -> handlers.onClickFriend(user)}
```

**Or**

```
<variable name="position" type="Integer"/>
```

and then

```
android:onClick="@{() -> handlers.onClickFriend(position)}
```